# Can I replace second character in text?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a macro in Excel to replace the second character in a text string.  For example, I have this number: 
`-4.023,31`

I am trying to replace the comma with an empty string.  I am using the following code:

`Columns("E:E").Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False`

I can replace the comma with a period, and the number looks like `-4.023.31` but I want it to look like `-4023.31`

Can this be done in Excel VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first replace the period with a null and then replace the comma with a period

For example:

```
Sub dural()
    With Range("E:E")
        .Replace ".", ""
        .Replace ",", "."
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this is working. I change my macro by your advice     `Sheets("Raw Data open payments").Select Columns("E:E").Replace What:=".", Replacement:=Null, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _ :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False`

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want, I think.

```
=REPLACE(E1, FIND(",", E1), 1, "")
```

You'll have to copy it all the way down your sheet.

Comment: Missed the part about this being a macro...  If you wanted to do it in a formula in a spreadsheet, the above would work.  I'm going to leave this here just in case someone needs it.